# Regex Match Between Two Strings With Or Operator

Tags: sql, regex

I've tried searching for a solution to an answer to this but have only found the general question of searching between two strings.

Essentially I'm trying to find any SELECT statements that aren't used to create a table in a SQL script.

I'm currently using this regex in Sublime Text 3 : `;(\h|\v|/\*(?s).+?\*/)+((SELECT|SEL)(?s).+?;)`

The point is to find a SELECT statement that occurs after a ";" that can have either vertical blank space, horizontal blank space, or a comment block in between.

This fails to work when something is between to comment blocks.  For example

```
;
/*Comment Block*/
CREATE TABLE table AS SELECT * FROM other_table1 AS a INNER JOIN (
/*Comment Block*/
SELECT *
FROM other_table2
) AS b
ON a.key = b.key
;
```

will match because technically the CREATE TABLE is between a /* and a */.  I tried making the match non-greedy and that works if I use just the regex `/\*(?s).+?\*/`.  It will select only one comment block at a time, however when used with the OR operator "|" (Sorry if this isn't technically called an or operator)  it seems to be greedy.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Would you clarify your desired result on the sample?

Comment: Regular expression evaluation can depend on your particular RDBMS and version, which is missing. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

`(s).+?/\*` lazily matches all characters including new lines until `/*` is found. Once the regex engine finds the end of the first comment block it continues to match `SELECT`, which it can't. Since it is a lazy search, it would have given up any further search if it would have found `SELECT`, but it didn't therefore it *backtracks and continues*. It then finds the end of the second comment block after which it can find `SELECT`.

The fundamental misunderstanding your regex exhibits is the use of a lazy match where you need a non-backtracking match. Lazy does not mean that no backtracking occurs. Lazy means that *no unneeded* backtracking occurs.

The way to avoid backtracking is by use of an atomic group, e.g. `(?>example atomic group)`. Your regex then becomes:

`;(?>\h|\v|/\*(?s).+?\*/)+((SELECT|SEL)(?s).+?;)`

See this in [action](http://regex101.com/r/hP3yJ9).

Another way to avoid this problem is by avoiding searching for all characters within the comment block. The way to achieve this is (obviously) to match all character not beginning with a `*` followed by a `/` inside a comment block. This translates to `([^*]|\*(?=/))+`. Your regex then becomes:

`;(\h|\v|/\*([^*]|\*(?=/))+\*/)+((SELECT|SEL)(?s).+?;)`

See this in [action](http://regex101.com/r/sF9pB2)